# Insert a circular progress bar in a View Pager android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, progress-bar

I have a View Pager which consists in 25 fragments (each one full of text coming from strings) and a grid which is the first fragment to be shown. The problem is that when I load the app it takes from 5 to 10 seconds to start responding, then it works really fluently. I cannot reduce loading times as I need all the fragments loaded at the same time. Therefore I would like a circular Progress Bar (the spinning one) for 3-4 seconds.

This is my main activity:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle(R.string.title_activity_afabeto);  

fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, GRID.class.getName()));
fragmentTitles.add(getString(R.string.title_activity_afabeto));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, A.class.getName()));
fragmentTitles.add(A.class.getSimpleName());
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, B.class.getName()));
fragmentTitles.add(B.class.getSimpleName());
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, C.class.getName()));
fragmentTitles.add(C.class.getSimpleName());
.
.
.
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Z.class.getName()));
fragmentTitles.add(Z.class.getSimpleName());
//
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
View pagerStrip = findViewById(R.id.pagerTabStrip);

if (pagerStrip instanceof PagerTabStrip) {
    PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) pagerStrip;
    pagerTabStrip.setDrawFullUnderline(true);
    pagerTabStrip.setTabIndicatorColorResource(android.R.color.holo_red_dark);
    // pagerTabStrip.setTextColor(color.white);
} else if (pagerStrip instanceof PagerTitleStrip) {
    PagerTitleStrip pagerTitleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) pagerStrip;
    pagerTitleStrip.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
}

this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments, fragmentTitles);
mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(fragments.size());

    }


public ViewPager getViewPager() {
if (null == mViewPager) {
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
}
return mViewPager;
}
```

Comment: *Therefore I would like a circular Progress Bar (the spinning one) for 3-4 seconds.* - if you're loading everything on the main UI thread you can't, otherwise inserting a `ProgressBar` shouldn't be too difficult. *I cannot reduce loading times as I need all the fragments loaded at the same time.*  - I somehow doubt you really need to load all those fragments at once and even more, keep them all in the `ViewPager`.

Comment: why do you need to load them all like that?

Comment: because if I do not load them all, when I select the fragment (A, B...) from the grid, it is not really fluent passing through all the pages

Comment: Again, that's not a reason to do what you do now. Do the data loading on a background thread and add a `ProgressBar` to each fragment. You'll then make the switch very fast and show the `ProgressBar` of the fragment while the data is loaded. With a loading manager you can make some assumption and increase the perceived speed for the user.

Comment: Ah, I got it! Thank you really much! Only one last question, is there any tutorial which explains how to load data in background? Or could you give me some code for my purposes? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments here is what you might need - an AsyncTask and and indeterminate progress bar. You can re-use your current code for obtaining the data. Just make sure you don't do any screen I/O from the background task.

```
public class MyBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", getString(R.string.wait_for_communication), true);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... answer) {
        // do your data stuff here

        // this return type is the 3rd data type in the declaration
        return true; 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        if ( !success ) {
            // Some kind of error occurred
            AlertDialog.Builder errorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            errorDialog.setTitle("Error Notice");
            errorDialog.setMessage("Error Message");
            errorDialog.show();
        }

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```